# Xcode documentation update items stuck on 'Getting...'

Tags: iphone, xcode

I installed Xcode 3.2.1 with the latest iPhone SDK, but the developer documentation for certain classes says it is "preliminary" and was last updated in early 2009. I know that it's not "preliminary" and Apple online developer docs confirm it. I went to Preferences > Documentation and noticed that the iPhone 3.1 Library item has greyed out "Getting..." text next to it. Is this normal or was the update process somehow interrupted and is now stuck? How can I fix it to download the latest iPhone docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode is probably downloading; check your network or file I/O traffic.  (In a shell, you can look at `$TMPDIR/../DocSet_Downloads`.)

If it is indeed downloading, you may have not waited long enough for it to finish. Try leaving Xcode open overnight.  (And file a bug; zero feedback for a multi-hour process in many cases is just crazy.)

Comment: Bingo! It was indeed downloading them.